Advanced configuration removed AutoMapper
I am upgrading a project .net core 3.1 to .dotnet8 , also upgrading nugets too like
I upgraded AutoMapper "10.1.1" to "13.0.0" and get this error

Apparently , this propery removed from IMapperConfigurationExpression
Does anybody know How can achieve the same thing with this new version?

Since AutoMapper11 it has been hidden so following the document to get the modification https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/11.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#forallmaps-forallpropertymaps-advanced-and-other-missing-apis

Thank you  Fengzhi Zhou , this is very useful for me

So its just needed AutoMapper.Internal using and usage is like this

